# Cannot get any loudness from microphones on Windows 11 laptop

Tags: usb, windows-11, microphone, sound-card

**Context**

I am trying to set headphones on a laptop for video meetings.

**Devices**

- Laptop model: Asus ProArt StudioBook H5600QM.
- Windows version: 11 Pro 21H2
- Headsets: Senheiser GSP 500 and Senheiser GSP 600
- Sound cards tested on that laptop: Native Instruments Komplete Audio 1, Sabrent "USB External Stereo 3D Sound Adapter | Black"

**Problem description**

When I use "Realtek Audio Microphone Array" which is the PC's built-in microphone, people can hear me. I only reach something around -3.6 dB speaking loud, which I think is already quiet... But I would like to avoid any "aerial" sound in meetings (this why I have headsets).
I have headsets Senheiser GSP 500 and Senheiser GSP 600. Both work fine on other PCs.
But on the laptop, I cannot get any loudness from them... volume is extremely low or completely silent.
The laptop does not have a microphone input, I tried connecting them using USB adaptors "Native Instruments Komplete Audio 1" and Sabrent "USB External Stereo 3D Sound Adapter | Black".
No success, microphones cannot get heard.

I supposedly know how to connect audio devices, even more complex than this... so I already went a bit everywhere in the sound settings... (it seems like Windows 11 has it's own layer of settings which is a bit confusing at times but the old style sound settings can be found after a few clicks)

System "toubleshooting" options are only about output/speakers, so nothing about microphones.

I'm thinking of getting something on USB-C, just because this laptop does not have a lot of USB-A, and the USB-A male plugs are really "floating" in the female plugs on both sides of the PC... but I made sure to test sound with correct plugging.

What could I do to further diagnose or fix this? Thank you.

---

**Edit - Progress:** maybe problem is solved, but I will only know next time I try to use headphones for a meeting.

I installed *Creative Sound Blaster G3* (so I have not tested with the other cards).

Microphone did not work at first.

*I found  "Troubleshoot input" and "Troubleshoot output" somewhere further in the Windows 11 sound menu, which is a different than when I had looked to "Troubleshoot" at first. I told it to troubleshoot the microphone, it said that the microphone was not selected as input... though it was... then it asked me if it had solved the problem... it had not. I had now no microphone selected and Windows Sound Recorder would crash when hitting record.*

Then I went in the old Sound Blaster G3 Microphone configuration and checked "Listen to this device" of something like that.

From there I noticed that both Windows Sound Recorder and Windows Sound microphone test were getting good loudness from microphone.

I unchecked "Listen to this device" and noticed that now they weren't receiving anything anymore, again...

**This is not how it should work.** You should be able to use a device as input without "Listening to it" in the output mix.  But it looks like selecting it at least first time triggers something in Windows sound mechanisms.

For some reason **after** I did this, with "Listen to this device" remaining unchecked:

- Good: Windows Microphone sound test gets loudness.
- Bad: Windows Sound Recorder still only records silence.
- Good: I tried with another sound software (iZotope RX) and this one recorded fine.
- Unknown yet: I do not see any sound test option in Microsoft Teams for browser, so that will have to wait for next use...

Comment: You should remove your answer from your question and put any additional relevant information in your answer

Comment: In the question is the progression on testing stuff and getting knowledge about the problem. In the answer, there is complete information on how to solve the problem. So everything is at the right place I think.

Comment: You don't have to indicate an edit when authoring a question.

Comment: I think that it makes it clearer that it's a second step in trying to solve the question. That's why I wrote it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Since I had a meeting today, I can now confirm that the solution was in the "progress" edit of the question.*

For some weird reason, checking `Listen to this device` "unlocked"  the sound of the microphone, even if I turned `Listen to this device` `off afterwards...

For the configuration I wanted, I should not have had to use `Listen to this device` at all, so this seems to me like a bug in the system.

*(The solution was not tried with the other microphones nor another Win11 system.)*

Comment: “Listen to this device” is a feature that has been around awhile and is not unique to Windows 11, it’s intention, is to allow you to hear yourself while you talk. Most USB headphones have this feature due to ability to provide additional hardware.

Comment: Yes, but the trick here is that I was normally not supposed to need it at all. Turning it ON at least once "triggers" the microphone to work properly, even if I disable “Listen to this device” afterwards. (Which seems to me like a bug somewhere in the system...)